# Apache Beam: What is the difference between DoFn and SimpleFunction?

Tags: java, apache-beam

While reading about processing streaming elements in apache beam using Java, I came across `DoFn<InputT, OutputT>` and then across `SimpleFunction<InputT, OutputT>`.

Both of these look similar to me and I find it difficult to understand the difference.

Can someone explain the difference in layman terms?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Conceptually you can think of `SimpleFunction` is a simple case of `DoFn`:

- `SimpleFunction<InputT, OutputT>`:

  - simple input to output mapping function;
  - single input produces single output;
  - statically typed, you have to `@Override` the `apply()` method;
  - doesn't depend on computation context;
  - can't use Beam state APIs;
  - example use case: `MapElements.via(simpleFunction)` to convert/modify elements one by one, producing one output for each element;
- `DoFn<InputT, OutputT>`:

  - executed with `ParDo`;
  - exposed to the context (timestamp, window pane, etc);
  - can consume side inputs;
  - can produce multiple outputs or no outputs at all;
  - can produce side outputs;
  - can use Beam's persistent state APIs;
  - dynamically typed;
  - example use case: read objects from a stream, filter, accumulate them, perform aggregations, convert them, and dispatch to different outputs;

You can find more specific examples and use cases for [`ParDos` in the dev guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo).

[This part](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#lightweight-dofns) mentions the `MapElements`, which is the use case for `SimpleFunctions`

Comment: So, just like FlatMap is a high-level fn of ParDo, can SimpleFunction be considered a higher level fn of DoFn?